# Java BigInteger Comparison

Tags: java

Can you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong in this code:

```
package javaapplication19;

public class JavaApplication19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3, bi4;
        bi1 = new BigInteger(123456789);
        bi2 = new BigInteger(0);
        bi3 = new BigInteger(123456789);
        bi4 = new BigInteger(0);

        for (bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
                bi2.compareTo(bi3) > 0;
                bi2 = bi2.add(1)) {
            if(bi4.compareTo(bi1) == 0) {
                System.out.println("bulduk bulduk" + bi4);
            }
            else
            {
                bi4 = bi4.add(1);
            } 
        }         
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Not supported yet.    at
>   javaapplication19.BigInteger.(BigInteger.java:19)   at
>   javaapplication19.JavaApplication19.main(JavaApplication19.java:19)
>   C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Thank you for your help

Comment: please point out line 19 in your code.

Comment: https://s18.postimg.org/5xn49ef3t/Capture.png  this is the screenshot.

Comment: Given the exception, that sounds like you're using a somewhat broken version of Java... what's your environment?

Comment: The problem is in `BigInteger` implementation.

Comment: We can't guess why you get errors, from custom classes that you don't show us .

Answer (score 2):

According to your stack trace, it means that **your class** `javaapplication19.BigInteger` (not `java.math.BigInteger`) doesn't support a constructor with a `int` as parameter. Check **your class** `javaapplication19.BigInteger` and you will know.

You should have something like this:

```
class BigInteger {
    ...
    BigInteger(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
    }
    ...
```

---

If you want to use `java.math.BigInteger` instead of `javaapplication19.BigInteger`, you will need to import it explicitly with `import java.math.BigInteger;` otherwise by default it will use the class `BigInteger` of your package `javaapplication19`.

Once you will use the correct `BigInteger` class, you will have to use [`BigInteger.valueOf(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-) to create your instances and [`BigInteger.add(BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-) to add values as next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3, bi4;
    bi1 = BigInteger.valueOf(123456789L);
    bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
    bi3 = BigInteger.valueOf(123456789L);
    bi4 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);

    for (bi2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0L);
         bi2.compareTo(bi3) > 0;
         bi2 = bi2.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        if(bi4.compareTo(bi1) == 0) {
            System.out.println("bulduk bulduk" + bi4);
        } else {
            bi4 = bi4.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whoever down voted, please check my response update

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have your own custom `BigInteger` on the classpath throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You could use the [built-in version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead:

```
bi1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
```

Comment: Check the stack trace, it doesn't use `java.math.BigInteger` but `javaapplication19.BigInteger`

Comment: Seems like re-inventing the wheel having another `BigInteger` on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a BigInteger constructor that takes a single integer, or a single long.

Answer (score 0):

constructor is worng. replace

```
bi1 = new BigInteger(123456789);
```

by

```
bi1 = BigInteger.valueOf(123456789L);
```

You need to study the class BigInteger in Java API.

Comment: Check the stack trace, it doesn't use `java.math.BigInteger` but `javaapplication19.BigInteger`